# How to install psycopg2 on el capitan?

Tags: postgresql, pip, psycopg2, imdbpy

I installed pip and then tried running sudo pip install psycopg2. I then get the Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

I'm not sure what this means.

I was running the imdbpy script to populate my postgres database, but I received ImportError: Cannot find a PostgreSQL driver, tried psycopg

I tried to install psycopg because of this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you can solve it installing this program (if you are linux User):

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

Or visit this web-site: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the right version of setuptools `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: When I ran that, it says that Requirements already up-to-date

Comment: Oh yeah I also wanted to note that I installed postgres through the .dmg and I a also using the pgadmin3 to manage it

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I would recommend you remove the Postgres installed using the '.dmg' file and install Postgres using **homebrew**.

Improper configuration caused the failure with error code 1.

I say this because homebrew takes care of linking everything to PATH and the other necessary setup/configuration to ensure you can start using it right away.

Use

```
brew doctor
brew update
```

then

```
brew install postgresql
```

You can find decent info [here](https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb).

Once that is complete, you can run the command

```
pip install psycopg2
```

That should work for you without any errors.

You can also check the location of pg_config using

```
which pg_config
```

This is what psycopg is looking for during the pip installation and causing the failure.

Hope that helps.